# MPI_Reduce with MPI_SUM is not working

Tags: c++, mpi, reduce

I am trying to simply sum up all variables called "train_hr" and "test_hr" from all 10 processors and store and print the sum on processor 0. I checked to make sure the individual sums are NOT 0 (they are not, they are all in the 1000s). The sum it keeps reporting is 0. I have no idea why. I have looked at many examples of this, and I have done it exactly as instructed. Any help would be appreciated.

```
double train_hr = 0, test_hr = 0;
double train_hr_global = 0, test_hr_global = 0;

//Master processor
if (my_rank == 0) {
    // sends a task to each processor
    int curr_task = 0;
    for(i = 0; i < num_procs; i++) {
        if (curr_task < nsamples_all) {
            MPI_Send(&curr_task, 1, MPI_INT, i, 1, MPI_COMM_WORLD);
            curr_task++;
        }
    }
    int r;
    MPI_Status status;

    //keeps sending tasks to processors until there are no more tasks
    while (curr_task < nsamples_all) {
        MPI_Recv(&r, 1, MPI_INT, MPI_ANY_SOURCE, 1, MPI_COMM_WORLD, &status);
        MPI_Send(&curr_task, 1, MPI_INT, status.MPI_SOURCE, 1, MPI_COMM_WORLD);
        curr_task++;
    }
    //tell all processors to stop receiving
    int a = -1;
    for (i = 0; i < num_procs; i++) {
        MPI_Send(&a, 1, MPI_INT, i, 1, MPI_COMM_WORLD);
    }
}

//Helper processors
else {
    int stop = 1;
    while(stop != 0){
        int i;
        //Receives task OR stop alert from master
        MPI_Status status;
        MPI_Recv(&i, 1, MPI_INT, 0, 1, MPI_COMM_WORLD, &status);
        if (i == -1) {
            stop = 0;
        }
        //computations
        else{
            float r;
            //unimportant computations here
            train_hr += r;
            test_hr += r;   
            //Tells master processor it is done             
            MPI_Send(&i, 1, MPI_INT, 0, 1, MPI_COMM_WORLD);
        }
    }
}
//At this point I checked the current values of train_hr and test_hr on each helper processor. They are all non-zero.

MPI_Reduce(&train_hr, &train_hr_global, 1, MPI_INT, MPI_SUM, 0, MPI_COMM_WORLD);
MPI_Reduce(&test_hr, &test_hr_global, 1, MPI_INT, MPI_SUM, 0, MPI_COMM_WORLD);

//at this point, the vales of train_hr_global and test_hr_global on the master processor (processor 0) are 0 when they should be the sum of all the processors values.
}
```

Comment: I'm not sure this is your problem, but when you use `MPI_Reduce`, you give the address of `double`s, but tell MPI your sending `MPI_INT`. Shouldn't you be sending `MPI_Double`?

Comment: A minor point that doesn't address your problem: you should avoid calling the MPI processes processors. Call them either *processes* or *ranks*. Right now, you may be using MPI to split up the job among the processors of your laptop, but each MPI *process* need not be a single processor. Changing your mindset now will help your understanding later if you end up creating a single MPI *process* for several processors all located on a single compute node.